# How to correctly parse rune parameter in YAML file

Tags: go, yaml

I tried to pass rune parameter in Yaml like this:

```
CsvDelimiter: ';'
```

then i parse yaml to struct

```
type Params struct {
  ...
  CsvDelimiter rune `yaml: "CsvDelimiter"`
  ...
}
```

but then Params.CsvDelimiter is empty

how correctly pass rune parameters from Yaml?

Comment: Can you provide your code rather than describing what it does? Check out creating a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What yaml package are you using? The commonly used one `gopkg.in/yaml.v3` and `v2` returns an error that clearly states that what you want is not supported *"cannot unmarshal !!str `;` into int32"* (the Go rune type is an int32, fyi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The YAML unmarshaler does not know how to handle a rune, but you can extract a rune from the string like this.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Params struct {
    CsvDelimiter string `yaml:"CsvDelimiter"`
}

func main() {
    str := `CsvDelimiter: ';'`
    params := Params{}
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &params)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(rune(params.CsvDelimiter[0]))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using the `gopkg.in/yaml.v3` package, you could declare a custom rune type and have it implement the [`Unmarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3?utm_source=godoc#Unmarshaler) interface.

```golang
type Rune rune

func (r *Rune) UnmarshalYAML(n *yaml.Node) error {
    var s string
    if err := n.Decode(&s); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    rn, _ := utf8.DecodeRune([]byte(s))
    *r = Rune(rn)
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/UDYU_EAJNqn